# MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not show a MediaQuery error shown even though MediaQuery not used in app

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in Flutter and I am trying to make a simple app with an AppBar with a title showing the text "Hi there"

When executing the code via Android Studio, I am always receiving the error

```
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
```

Why is this error called even though I don't call MediaQuery.of()? How do I solve this problem

I first thought this was an issue with flutter or Android Studio. I used flutter doctor and everything was fine. The exact code is shown below:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.706], locale
    en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I realized that the Flutter framework itself probably wasn't a problem.

I then decided to restart Android Studio because that itself could solve the problem on its own. Unfortunately, the pesky error had still shown

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(myApp());

class myApp extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hi there")
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I expected to see an AppBar with a title stating "Hi There", but instead I had received an error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MediaQuery` is used by `Scaffold` internal components to layout its children as evident from its [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart). Thus, it needs to be wrapped inside a widget which will provide a `MediaQuery`, like a `MaterialApp` widget, which inherits from [`WidgetsApp`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp-class.html) :

```
void main() => runApp(myApp());

class myApp extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Hi there")
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```